# How variable length arrays are aligned in C?

Tags: c

What logic is used to align variable length arrays (VLAs) in C99?

I'm considering allocating storage on the stack for arbitrary objects with unknown alignment requirements and so would need the strictest alignment. I would prefer avoiding `alloca()` and using (`char`) VLAs instead as they're better standardized.

My tests with GCC haven't managed to disprove they're aligned on anything less than 16 bytes.

Comment: I would guess, that memory alignments are not part of the C standard.

Comment: Use `malloc` and avoid such experiments. Why you need VLA instead of `malloc`? It looks like "modern language"? If this is the reason - use Python, Perl, etc.

Comment: @i486 - premature optimization, what else :)? Seriously, although it's a good advice, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: VLAs is basically the same as using `alloca`. Alignement will automatically be correct depending on your platform.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelWalz! Do you have any references supporting that?

Comment: @ceving I failed to find that in C99 myself, but I'm not that good at interpreting it.

Comment: I suppose you could always align manually, i.e. create an array which is ALIGN_CHUNK_SIZE-1 larger than needed and return the address to an offset if the alignment is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterA.Schneider! Yeah, I might as well resort to that since so far there's no consensus nor any authoritative info. Still the question is interesting by itself.

Comment: And I'm sure that you cannot rely on the alignment of a char array. Try compiling with -Os for reduced size, and try other compilers and for other platforms.

Comment: @ceving, your guess is just wrong

Comment: @JensGustedt I expect ceving meant the VLA alignment is not specified. However, although I couldn't find it myself, I doubt it's not actually there.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Tried -Os (no change) and ARM (got down to 8 bytes, but that's likely due to drop to 32 bits) - no luck.

Comment: @spbnick, to work properly, arrays have to align their elements the same way as an ordinary variable of the same type. What do you expect differently?

Comment: @JensGustedt Well, I'm kind of hoping they would have strictest alignment requirements spelled out somewhere due to potential implementation complexity. That wouldn't break anything.

Comment: @spbnick: it is very rare for a standard to require more than necessary, and much less because someone thinks the excess requirement is easier to implement. An implementation is free to align more strictly than necessary, but it is also free to provide only the required alignment, whether or not that is more work for the implementers.

Comment: @rici Yeah, this is reasonable. Logic ruins everything as usual, don't hope - think :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

VLAs are aligned same way as the normal arrays.

Which means that allocating array of `char`s and storing `int` into it is not going to work, if you want to access that integer directly.

You can use `_Alignof` to determine alignment for type and calculate needed adjustments manually, but even then it's implementation defined at best.

I believe that you might have to disable strict aliasing on your compiler for this to work.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide any references to substantiate this?

Comment: And yeah, I don't know the type, I only know the size. Hmm, actually I can add the alignment to the type description, but it would be nice to avoid that.

Comment: @spbnick, the C standard says so. `_Alignof` and `_Alignas` have been introduced with C11, so you'd need  a compiler that supports this version.

Comment: @spbnick Unfortunately it's hard to find compact and specific reference to quote, since VLAs are not specificly mentioned in alignment section of the C standard.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks a lot! Aargh, so far it looks like I'll have to forget about it and just align it myself on the strictest alignment.

Comment: Could you stick your char VLA in a union with a `intmax_t`, a `long double` and a `void *`? That would probably be fairly maximally aligned. Perhaps add a function pointer type to the union for good measure!